# pocketbase: command not found

Tags: pocketbase

I am trying to set up pocketbase on a Debian server.

On the server, I created a dir called `pb` and used `scp` to transfer over the pocketbase file I downloaded from [here](https://pocketbase.io/docs/).

I downloaded all three linux packages:

- [`pocketbase_0.10.2_linux_amd64.zip`](https://github.com/pocketbase/pocketbase/releases/download/v0.10.2/pocketbase_0.10.2_linux_amd64.zip)
- [`pocketbase_0.10.2_linux_arm64.zip`](https://github.com/pocketbase/pocketbase/releases/download/v0.10.2/pocketbase_0.10.2_linux_arm64.zip)
- [`pocketbase_0.10.2_linux_armv7.zip`](https://github.com/pocketbase/pocketbase/releases/download/v0.10.2/pocketbase_0.10.2_linux_armv7.zip)

I downloaded each file, unzipped it and then moved the `pocketbase` file over to the server.

(Note: I've downloaded these onto a windows machine and then SCP pocketbase file over to my server.)

When I run `pocketbase serve`, I get the error `command not found`.

Comment: I had this issue by stupidly trying to serve the Windows .exe executable on a Debian Linux remote machine instead of serving the Linux version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Execute it as instructed by pocketbase's documentation if you are within the same directory as the bin file:

`./pocketbase serve`

If you want to run it as `pocketbase serve` alone you will need to move the bin file under `/usr/bin` or ideally `/usr/local/bin` which should be under your system's `$PATH` variable.

https://pocketbase.io/docs/

Run `./pocketbase --help` or `./pocketbase [command] --help` for more assistance.